# Disable button when another button is been clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form am working on for a project which allows users to upload images, videos and YouTube videos and I will like users not to upload photos, videos and YouTube videos at the same time but am finding it difficult on how to disable the image button when video or YouTube button is been clicked, disable video button when image or YouTube button is been clicked and disable YouTube button when image or video button is been clicked. Below is my form and Jquery code I have written so far

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>" name="post-box" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <div class="post_box_cont">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="post_box" placeholder="Post something..." onkeyup="count_post_box_char(this, 500)"></textarea>

                        <div class="mt-1">
                            <button class="post_box_but">
                                <span class="icon icon-location"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention people by typing @ before their username e.g. @aaron">
                                <span class="icon icon-at"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" id="image">
                                <span class="icon icon-image"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" id="video">
                                <span class="icon icon-video"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" id="youtube">
                                <span class="icon icon-youtube"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_upload_but">
                                <b>Post</b>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // var
    var img = $("#image");
    var video = $("#video");
    var youtube = $("#youtube");

    img.click(function(){
        $("#video").attr("disabled='disabled'");
        $("#youtube").attr("disabled='disabled'");
    }); 

  video.click(function(){
        img.attr("disabled='disabled'");
        youtube.attr("disabled='disabled'");
    });

   youtube.click(function(){
        img.attr("disabled='disabled'");
        video.attr("disabled='disabled'");
    }); 


});
```

Comment: you can use radio instead of button.

Comment: This is exactly what radio's are for - selecting a single choice from multiple (given there's an additional "post" button) and let the browser handle it for you.  You can then style them so they look like buttons rather than radios and there's *zero* javascript required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should listen to event like

```
    img.on("click", function(){
```

2. You can disable button like

```
    attr("disabled", true);
```

```js
// var
    var img = $("#image");
    var video = $("#video");
    var youtube = $("#youtube");

    img.on("click", function(){
        video.attr("disabled", true);
        youtube.attr("disabled", true);
    }); 

  video.on("click", function(){
        img.attr("disabled", true);
        youtube.attr("disabled", true);
    });

   youtube.on("click", function(){
        img.attr("disabled", true);
        video.attr("disabled", true);
    });
    
    $("#btnReset").on("click", function(){
        img.attr("disabled", false);
        video.attr("disabled", false);
        youtube.attr("disabled", false);
    });
```

```css
.post_box_but:disabled{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <div class="post_box_cont">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="post_box" placeholder="Post something..." onkeyup="count_post_box_char(this, 500)"></textarea>

                        <div class="mt-1">
                            <button class="post_box_but">
                                <span class="icon icon-location"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention people by typing @ before their username e.g. @aaron">
                                <span class="icon icon-at"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" id="image">
                                <span class="icon icon-image"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" id="video">
                                <span class="icon icon-video"></span>
                            </button>

                            <button class="post_box_but" id="youtube">
                                <span class="icon icon-youtube"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="post_box_upload_but" id="btnReset">
                                <b>Reset_Button</b>
                            </button>
                            <button class="post_box_upload_but">
                                <b>Post</b>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `img.click` is a synonym for `img.on("click",` - despite attempts at otherwise, they're still both valid and will be for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thank you! but how do I remove the disabled attribute when either video or YouTube  button is been clicked

Comment: You just set `attr("disabled", false)`

Comment: Which means I have to create another click function to solve that right? @Phong

Comment: Whenever one button is clicked, the rest of the buttons will be disabled. So you cannot click again. What does the behavior do you want?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with **Reset_Button** for you, Please take a look at.